# Cannot find eccodes library while import cfgrib on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, grib, eccodes

I had issue on Windows 10 Pro (build: 19045.4170), python: 3.10.2.
Basic problem was in this line:

```
import cfgrib
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\userxyz\Desktop\analyza_grib.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cfgrib
  File "C:\Users\userxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .cfmessage import COMPUTED_KEYS
  File "C:\Users\userxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\cfmessage.py", line 29, in <module>
    from . import abc, messages
  File "C:\Users\userxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cfgrib\messages.py", line 28, in <module>
    import eccodes  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\userxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eccodes\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .eccodes import *  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\userxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eccodes\eccodes.py", line 12, in <module>
    from gribapi import (
  File "C:\Users\userxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gribapi\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .gribapi import *  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\userxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gribapi\gribapi.py", line 34, in <module>
    from gribapi.errors import GribInternalError
  File "C:\Users\userxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gribapi\errors.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .bindings import ENC, ffi, lib
  File "C:\Users\userxyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gribapi\bindings.py", line 35, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot find the ecCodes library")
RuntimeError: Cannot find the ecCodes library
```

Issue seems to be resolved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76594735/3818277).
(So basically installing package ecmwflibs).
I only use pip install and no conda environment. This is my versions of packages now:
ecmwflibs: 0.6.3, eccodes: 2.34.1, cfgrib: 0.9.9.0.
Is there a better solution, or can someone explain what happened?